# Woocommerce product variation price list

Tags: woocommerce, product, price, product-variations

im trying to figure out how to show all variation prices as text in single product page.

ex if product has 5 diffrent prices, 1 - 500, 2 - 900, 3 - 2100, 4 - 2500, 5 - 3000
i want it to show in text on all product pages.

as this:

VARIATIONS
1 - 500
2 - 900.

right now i do this manually, write them all up so ppl dont have to scroll down in the roll down menu to se what prices are but i want this done automaticly when i change the prices so i dont have to change this text everythime. i tryed diffrent hooks but couldnt find right one.

i tried this one but cant the hook to work and show it in product page

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_variable_price_html', 'custom_price_format', 10, 2 );
function custom_price_format( $price, $product ) {

    // 1. Variable products
    if( $product->is_type('variable') ){

        // Searching for the default variation
        $default_attributes = $product->get_default_attributes();
        // Loop through available variations
        foreach($product->get_available_variations() as $variation){
            $found = true; // Initializing
            // Loop through variation attributes
            foreach( $variation['attributes'] as $key => $value ){
                $taxonomy = str_replace( 'attribute_', '', $key );
                // Searching for a matching variation as default
                if( isset($default_attributes[$taxonomy]) && $default_attributes[$taxonomy] != $value ){
                    $found = false;
                    break;
                }
            }
            // When it's found we set it and we stop the main loop
            if( $found ) {
                $default_variaton = $variation;
                break;
            } // If not we continue
            else {
                continue;
            }
        }
        // Get the default variation prices or if not set the variable product min prices
        $regular_price = isset($default_variaton) ? $default_variaton['display_price']: $product->get_variation_regular_price( 'min', true );
        $sale_price = isset($default_variaton) ? $default_variaton['display_regular_price']: $product->get_variation_sale_price( 'min', true );
    }
    // 2. Other products types
    else {
        $regular_price = $product->get_regular_price();
        $sale_price    = $product->get_sale_price();
    }

    // Formatting the price
    if ( $regular_price !== $sale_price && $product->is_on_sale()) {
        // Percentage calculation and text
        $percentage = round( ( $regular_price - $sale_price ) / $regular_price * 100 ).'%';
        $percentage_txt = __(' Save', 'woocommerce' ).' '.$percentage;

        $price = '<del>' . wc_price($regular_price) . '</del> <ins>' . wc_price($sale_price) . $percentage_txt . '</ins>';
    }
    return $price;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place the following function in your functions.php . You can replace `get_price_html()` with `$product->get_price();` or `$product->get_regular_price();` `$product->get_sale_price();` depending on how you want to show your data.

```
function list_variation_prices() {
    global $product;
    if($product->get_type() === 'variable'):
        $variations = $product->get_children();
        if($variations):
            echo '<ul>';
            foreach($variations as $variation):
                $vproduct = wc_get_product($variation);
                echo '<li>'.$vproduct->get_price_html().'</li>';
            endforeach;
            echo '</ul>';
        endif;
    endif;
}
/** Change priority to change where you want to show it. Default priorities
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title - 5
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_rating - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price - 10
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt - 20
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart - 30
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta - 40
     * @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing - 50
     * @hooked WC_Structured_Data::generate_product_data() - 60
*/
add_action('woocommerce_single_product_summary','list_variation_prices',25);
```

Comment: looks good. i have changed the
add_action('woocommerce_short_description','list_variation_prices',25);
to show it in short description. it works. however it repeats itself somehow, so i se the prices 14 times ( https://anonfiles.com/z2qd56ydwf/vcccv_png )
and can i add the amount before the price? now i se all prices, ex
50$
100$
can i add so i se variation before ex
2 pieces - 50 $
4 pieces - 100$

Comment: I have tested this on clean storefront theme and there are no problems. Can you var_dump($variatons) and see how many variation ids its returning ? What do you mean by  amount before the price ?