# get_post_meta() get the lowest regular price from all variations

Tags: php, woocommerce

I would like to find the lowest regular price of all variations. For this I have written the following code:

```html
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_add_to_cart_form', 'preis_von' );
function preis_von() {
    global $product;
    global $post;
    $theproductid = array(15174, 15175);
    $product_id = method_exists( $product, 'get_id' ) ? $product->get_id() : $product->id;
    if(in_array($product_id, $theproductid)) {
        $prices = min(get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', true ));
        //rsort($prices); // sort in descending order
        //$minPrice=min($prices);
        echo '<div id="preisab" class="abpreis">Preis ab '.$prices.'€ pro Won</div>';
         ?>
        <script>
        jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
            $( ".variations_form" ).on( "woocommerce_variation_select_change", function () {
                document.getElementById("preisab").innerHTML= " ";
         });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    }
}
```

But there is no output. If I use the variation ID instead of $post->ID, I get the output of the regular price for the variation. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Not exactly sure about the WooCommerce data model - but `get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_regular_price', true )` should get you _one_ price, no? I don't think this will get you the prices of all variations. You will have to get the variations first, and then loop over them, like https://stackoverflow.com/a/70433145/1427878

Comment: How to get lowest price - $product->get_variation_price(); . Read more about get_variation_price - https://wp-kama.com/filecode/woocommerce/includes/class-wc-product-variable.php#L125-130